# C++ text file into array. (Newbie)

Tags: c++

Hello everyone and sry in advance for the newbie question but i didn't find any topic specific to my problem. I have a text file of products as shown below:

//No. //Description //Price

100          Office_seat       102.99

200          Desk              224.99

300          Computer_desk      45.49

400          Desk_Lamb          23.99

500          Bookcase           89.49

i want to read it and save it in an array from which i will search for the Product_pin later and calculate the total price of a client's purchase.

tried something like the code i am posting but i think i am starting it all wrong. I would be gratefull for any advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream file("Proionta.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        string myArray[15];
        for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
            file>>myArray[i];

        }
    }
system ("pause");
}
```

Should i try to make a function to put the code in it?

Comment: Using the stream operator to a `std::string` won't necessarily give you whole lines of input. If that's what you want, I suggest you look into [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: _i think i am starting it all wrong._ You think? Why do you think that way? Can you share _any_ details about the problem you are facing? Because the problem is unclear, from the question in its current form.

Comment: I have to create a function which will read the data from the .txt file and save it in an array. After that i have to make a 2nd function which will search for the product code in the array created above. I will also have to create a class which will add the prices from the products each client will choose and print it in the end. (it's for a class project).

Comment: @George_Vas Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: There are too many of these kind of questions.  You can find more by searching the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file array".  You did search first?

Comment: Start with defining a data structure where you can store the information for one item.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start out with the record modeling concept, then get primitive.

You want to *model* the text line as a *record*:

```
struct Record
{
  unsigned int number;
  std::string  description;
  double       price;
};
```

The next step would be to overload `operator>>` for the `Record`:

```
struct Record
{
  unsigned int number;
  std::string  description;
  double       price;

  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  input >> r.number >> r.description >> r.price;
  return input;
}
```

Using the above code, you can read in a file:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (my_text_file >> r)
{
  database.push_back(r);
}
```

**Edit 1:  Without `struct`**
Let's say you don't know about how to use `class` or `struct`.
Each field can be read separately:

```
unsigned int number;
std::string  description;
double price;
while (my_text_file >> number >> description >> price)
{
  // Do something with number, description, price
}
```

**Edit 2: Arrays vs. vector**
Many assignments require you to do something with the data, like averages or searches.  This usually requires you to save the data.
Two popular containers (from a student's point of view) are the array and `std::vector`.

Arrays are not a good choice, because with File I/O, you're never quite sure how many records there are and arrays like to be static in capacity (never changing).  So you will need to do the resizing yourself:

```
static const unsigned int initial_capacity = 16U;
Record database[initial_capacity];
unsigned int capacity = initial_capacity;
Record r;
unsigned int items_read = 0;
while (my_text_file >> r)
{
  if (items_read < capacity)
  {
    database[items_read] = r;
    ++items_read;
  }
  else
  {
     // Allocate new, larger array
     // Copy items from old array to larger array.
     // Update capacity variable.
     // Delete old array
     // Change database pointer to new array
  }
}
```

A nice feature of `std::vector` is that you can access it like an array, and it will automatically increase in capacity as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you put in my question and the info you have provided me. I will try to use some of the ways you provided me and figure out what to do next.